# HTTP PUT request doesn't works

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, backend, mern

I development a app web with MERN to upload information about stundents in a school, so, I make my backend with MongoDB and JS and to make the request I used Axios library. For get the information about some student with the method GET this works so good, but when i tried to update some information about the student with the method PUT and doesn't update. In the console.log appears the new information but not on the backend, this is my code where i try to update this information

```
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { onLoadEvents3, onSetActiveEvent3, onUpdateEvent3 } from "../store";
import { systemApi } from "../api";
import Swal from "sweetalert2";

export const usePerDatStore = () => {
  const eventId = "64a5fc8e8f32a8a62adddf3b";
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const { event, activeEvent } = useSelector((state) => state.perdat);

  const setActiveEvent3 = (perdatEvent) => {
    console.log(perdatEvent);
    dispatch(onSetActiveEvent3(perdatEvent));
  };

  const startSavingEvent3 = async (perdatEvent) => {

    try {
      dispatch(onUpdateEvent3({...perdatEvent}));
      console.log("Data antes de entrar al backend", perdatEvent);
      const {data} = await systemApi.put(`/events/${eventId}`,perdatEvent);
      console.log("datos obtenidos del backend despues del put",data.evento.datos_personales);
      
      // Lógica adicional para guardar los datos editados en el backend
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      Swal.fire('Error al guardar', error.response.data.msg, 'error');
    }
  };

  const startLoadingEvents3 = async () => {
    try {
      const { data } = await systemApi.get(`/events/${eventId}`);
      const events = data.evento
     dispatch(onLoadEvents3(events));
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error al cargar el usuario");
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  return {
    activeEvent,
    event,
    setActiveEvent3,
    startSavingEvent3,
    startLoadingEvents3,
  };
};
```

and my systemApi.js to call axios and used the method i want
import axios from "axios";

```
import {getEnvVariables} from '../helpers'


const {VITE_API_URL} = getEnvVariables()

const systemApi = axios.create({

    baseURL: VITE_API_URL


})

//todo interceptores
systemApi.interceptors.request.use(config =>{
    
    config.headers ={
        ...config.headers,
        'x-token': localStorage.getItem('token')
    }
    
    
    return config;
})

export default systemApi
```

On my console.log appears the next output (when click it save the new information)

perdatEvente output:

```
Data antes de entrar al backend 
{fname: 'Christian', snumber: '18400282', career: 'Mehcatronic', group: '11A', vinculacion: 'CETSA', …}
age: "26"
birth: "2001-09-09T01:30:00.000Z"
career: "Mehcatronic"
col: "El batan"
fname: "Christian"
gender: "Male"
group: "11A"
hnumber : "#2200"
mail:"Christian.cetsa@gmail.com"
number:  "31113644888"
phone: "3111364"
snumber : "18400222282"
street: "Guadalupe Mero"
vinculacion: "CETSA"
```

This is the console.log from the data backend returns

data.event.datos_personales

```
    datos obtenidos del backend despues del put 
{fname: 'Christian', snumber: '18400282', career: 'Mehcatronic', group: '11A', vinculacion: 'CETSA', …}
age: "26"
birth: "2001-09-09T01:30:00.000Z"
career: "Mehcatronic"
col: "El batan"
fname: "Christian"
gender: "Male"
group: "11A"
hnumber: "#2200"
mail: "Christian.cetsa@gmail.com"
number: "31113644888"
phone: "31113644800000000000000"
snumber: "18400222282"
street: "Guadalupe Mero"
vinculacion: "CETSA"
```

On the headers appears everything is good and the change is done but not.
If needed some more information or another code such as slice or PerDat.jsx please let me know.

I hope you can help me.
Regards.
y8.

Comment: Are you quite sure you're supposed to use `PUT`, and not `POST`?  If it's a simple API, it's usually `GET` and `POST`.  Some more sophisticated APIs do use `PUT`.

Comment: yes, i need to use PUT because sometimes I need to update some student information which is already created. In fact, when I use Postman the PUT request works good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by doing the following:

```
const {data} = await systemApi.put(`/events/${eventId}`,{datos_personales:perdatEvent});
```

And works good!